# Google funding choices/admob with User Messaging Platform

Tags: admob, adsense

Is it possible to display the consent dialog for GDPR on Android in multiple languages?

I can only publish a single message in a single language.

I see no fitting method in the ump sdk.

I mean there has to be a way to do this, if not then this sdk makes no sense at all !?

Comment: I'm struggling about the same issue. Seems that it is for now

Comment: Can you explain a little more where you "publish a single message in a single language"?

Comment: Me too have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Don't you have an option to add secondary languages when you create a message in the Admob / Privacy and message settings?

Answer (score 1):

It's done automatically now. Google changed it.